# Call play() multiple times does not fire

Tags: jquery

I am sure I'm missing something obvious. But can anyone tell me why it only fires *once* onload and does not stack up?

```
$("#a")[0].play();
$("#a")[0].play();
$("#a")[0].play();
```

Comment: yes, I need them to fire in the row.

Comment: here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s8woqzde/

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/bv9yzjtp/

Comment: Also, you can’t automatically trigger play on an audio element without user interaction, due to browser restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that these event will fire in quick succession.

To have them fire in sequence the conceptual solution would be:

```
let count = 1; 
let audio = document.getElementById('a'); 
audio.onended = function() {
  if(count <= 2){
     count++;
     this.play();   
  } 
}; 
audio.play();
```

Provided by Carsten.

Fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/bv9yzjtp](https://jsfiddle.net/bv9yzjtp)